# Use a pointer in struct without seg fault

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm attempting to use pointers to make this struct's data dynamically allocated.

```
struct Stack
{
    int top;
    ItemT *items;
    int size;
};

StackP newStack()
{
    struct Stack s;
    StackP p = &s;

    p->top = -1;
    p->items = malloc(sizeof(ItemT) * DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
    p->size = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;

    return p;
}

void pushStack(StackP p, ItemT i)
{
    p->top++;
    p->size--;
    p->items[p->top] = i;
}
```

I have to use an array, and it is being separated from the struct via a pointer so that I can expand it without having to expand the struct. When I run a test of pushStack(), I get a seg fault. I've identified the line "`p->items[p->top] = i`" to be the issue, but I don't know why. I suspect the memory allocated in my constructor might be inaccessible from other functions. First, why am I getting a seg fault? Second, how can I fix the issue? (These functions are prototyped / declared in a separated .h file)

Comment: what is `p->size--;` for?  Another problem you may run into is having `p->top` be outside the bounds of how much memory you have allocated; you need to be careful about tracking this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your newStack function, you create the stack with:

```
struct Stack s;
StackP p = &s;
```

Unfortunately, as soon as the routine returns, the stucture `s` that `p` points to falls of the stack and goes away.  You really should do:

```
StackP p = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
```

and then at the end of the program, `free(p);` to cleanup.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that you're returning a pointer to a local instance of `Stack` (`s` in this case), you should also dynamically allocate the instance you're going to return:

```
StackP newStack()
{
    StackP p = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));

    p->top = -1;
    p->items = malloc(sizeof(ItemT) * DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
    p->size = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;

    return p;
}
```

Comment: and where exactly do you see `StackP` defined in OPs code?

Comment: @TonyTheLion Right above `struct Stack` definition. You will have to look closely though.

Comment: @TonyTheLion: It's obviously a `Stack*`. What's the problem?